# Monitor activity on AWS EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a requirement from a customer that wants to know for what purpose his EC2 instances are being used. The users are students, and they have elevated permissions on those EC2 instances. He wants a report that tells him which programs are being used on each instance. Are these students using python, mining Ethereum? Or what are they doing? Is there any tool for Windows and Linux that can help me with this?

I'm thinking to install an agent on each EC2 instance and get a list of the precesses that are being executed. But to get something useful from a list of processes list will be a lot of work. Any other suggestion?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like AWS System Manager service can help with this. I'll post my experience later.

https://aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/

Answer (score 1):

You want to look at EC2 System Manager.  There are two services that might help.

Inventory can collect information about patch levels, installed software, etc and create reports of the results.

For more details, Run Command will allow you to periodically run something like `ps -ef` across your fleet and also report on the results.

Answer (score -2):

Look into AWS Cloudtrail. It is native, so easy to add to your instances. Monitors and logs all activity you would be interested in auditing.
https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/

Comment: The OP wants to know what's happening inside the EC2 intance (eg. what programs are being executed). CloudTrail will not give this information.